# Create SAS table using PROC OPTMODEL

Tags: optimization, sas, mathematical-optimization, minimization

I need to transform the output from PROC OPTMODEL in a SAS table.

Browsing on the internet, I found it is possible to do that by using the CREATE DATA statement in the [PROC OPTMODEL](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/or/132/optmodel.pdf).

Specifically, I'm tryng to solve an optimization problem that aims to minimize the volatility under 2 constraints; the example script is the following one:

```
proc optmodel;;

    /* let x1, x2, x3, x4 be the amount invested in each asset */
    var x{1..&n.} >= 0;

    num coeff{1..&n., 1..&n.} = [&covariance_matrix.];
    num r{1..&n.} = [&return.];

    /* minimize the variance of the portfolio's total return */
    minimize f = sum{i in 1..&n., j in 1..&n.}coeff[i,j]*x[i]*x[j];

    /* subject to the following constraints */
    con BUDGET: sum{i in 1..&n.}x[i] <= &budget.;
    con GROWTH: sum{i in 1..&n.}r[i]*x[i] >= &growth. * &budget.;

    solve with NLP;
    
    create data weights from x;
    /* print the optimal solution */
    print x;

quit;
```

I aim to transform the vector x in a SAS table, in order to be able to use the weights that minimize the volatility; the log window shows the following error message:

> ERROR 650-782: The subscript count does not match array 'x', 2 NE 1.

Why do I get such error?Can someone can help me to get a solution?

In case the question is not clear, fell free to text me in the comment here below.

Thanks all in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by running the following statement:

> `create data weights from [n]x`

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a vector of variables from 1 to &n. You need to loop through each one.

```
create data weights from [i] = {1..&n}
    x[i]
;
```